# Animate ImageView From Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-imageview

Can't animate an ImageView from a onItemClickListener ListView's method. The ListView is inside a Fragment. Can someone suggest what should I do?

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

View view;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle sis){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listf);
    this.view= view;


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){


          ImageView i = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgv);
          AnimationSet as = new AnimationSet(true);
          Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim1);              
          Animation animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim2);
          as.addAnimation(animation1);
          as.addAnimation(animation2);
          i.setImageResource(R.drawable.logocpic1);
          i.startAnimation(as);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is imageview, is it n listview ?

Comment: No, it's on the main layout, like the fragment...

Comment: final ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgv);  put it into oncreate

Comment: i wrote accidently, i put the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you are having errors because you are doing UI operations in a not UI thread. you can use the code below,

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
View view;
ImageView i;
.
.
.
.

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
.
.
.   


   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         i = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgv);
      }
   });
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, that's beacause the section of code that i wrote above, is inside the class that extends the fragment...

Comment: Ok, i changed. If you should you inflated layout

Comment: Still doesn't work... Eclipse streess both loadAnimation methods and shows follow error: "The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the 
 arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int)"

Comment: try to replace this to getActivity()

Comment: tried before to post... it crashed during run-time when pressed listview's items :(...

Comment: talhakosen@gmail.com send me your code, i dont understand whatis the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
I think you have to try this following code it works for me....
```

Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getapplicationContext(), R.anim.anim1);

instead of

Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim1);

may be it works for u.

Answer (score 0):

please change to like

```
Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainFragment.this, R.anim.anim1);
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.